# how to replace the string of another txt file that matches the entire string in the txt file with the string that target string with linux command?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, centos7

Using the command below, I succeeded in replacing a string with [ talend template tag ] that matches the entire sentence in the temp.txt file within the target.txt file.

```
sed -e '/<\!-- talend template tag -->/ {' -e 'r temp.txt' -e 'd' -e '}' -i test_target.txt
```

**vi temp.txt**

```bash
<option value="load_csv_to_db_talend_template">[template]
 load_csv_to_db</option>
<option value="transform_db_to_view_talend_template">[template]
 transform_db_to_view</option>
```

**vi test_target.txt**

```bash
<select class="form-control" id="job_type" name="job_type">
  <option disabled selected value=""> {{ _("Select the type of Job") }} </option>                 
  <option value="jar_file">jar</option>
  <option value="sh_file">linux shell(*.sh)</option>                            
  <option value="python_file">python</option>
  <option value="talend_file">Talend</option>
  <option value="postgres_sql_file">PostgreSQL</option>
  <option value="oracle_sql_file">OracleSQL</option>                       
  <option value="linux_bash">linux bash command</option>
  <!-- talend template tag -->
</select>
```

**vi test_target.txt after sed command**

```bash
<select class="form-control" id="job_type" name="job_type">
  <option disabled selected value=""> {{ _("Select the type of Job") }} </option>
  <option value="jar_file">jar</option>
  <option value="sh_file">linux shell(*.sh)</option>
  <option value="python_file">python</option>
  <option value="talend_file">Talend</option>
  <option value="postgres_sql_file">PostgreSQL</option>
  <option value="oracle_sql_file">OracleSQL</option>
  <option value="linux_bash">linux bash command</option>
  <option value="extract_api_file_to_csv_talend_template">[template]
    extract_api_file_to_csv</option>
  <option value="extract_db_to_csv_talend_template">[template]
    extract_db_to_csv</option>
  <option value="load_csv_to_db_talend_template">[template]
    load_csv_to_db</option>
  <option value="transform_db_to_view_talend_template">[template]
    transform_db_to_view</option>
</select>
```

However, it failed to produce an instruction to restore the above results to their original state.

**expected [test_target.txt] after command (restored)**

```bash
<select class="form-control" id="job_type" name="job_type">
  <option disabled selected value=""> {{ _("Select the type of Job") }} </option>                 
  <option value="jar_file">jar</option>
  <option value="sh_file">linux shell(*.sh)</option>                            
  <option value="python_file">python</option>
  <option value="talend_file">Talend</option>
  <option value="postgres_sql_file">PostgreSQL</option>
  <option value="oracle_sql_file">OracleSQL</option>                       
  <option value="linux_bash">linux bash command</option>
  <!-- talend template tag -->
</select>
```

I want a Linux command to solve this.

PS. What I want to do is a separate order that has nothing to do with the previous work. In other words, I said restoring it for easy understanding, but it's not a restore job.

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you add sample input data and expected data in question. Also clarify what you mean by `instruction to restore the above results to their original state` ?

Comment: You should add a backup suffix to the `-i` option. This will save the original file to a backup file, and you can restore to the original state by copying the backup file.

Comment: @anubhava yes i did it now

Comment: Where is restore command? Why not save a copy of original with `-i.bak` option as Bammar is suggested?

Comment: @anubhava, I didn't understand your answer. Can you fill out a resolved example?

Comment: @Barmar, didn't understand your answer. Can you fill out a resolved example?

Comment: What didn't you understand. BTW, if you want to comment on a specific answer, use the comment button below the answer, this section is for comments about the question.

Comment: Show the command you have tried to restore the file in question

Answer (score 0):

Tell `sed` to save the original file in a backup file by adding a suffix to the `-i` option.

```
sed -e '/<\!-- talend template tag -->/ {' -e 'r temp.txt' -e 'd' -e '}' -i.bak test_target.txt
```

Then to restore the original, copy it back:

```
cp test_target.txt.bak test_target.txt
```

Comment: That's not the answer I want. What I want to do is work like a restore, but in reality it should work regardless of the previous work.(Not backup, Independented work before)

Comment: I can't think of a way to write a single `sed` command that does both a modification and  restore. When you modify the file, the original contents are lost and you can't recover it.

Comment: What I want to do is a separate order that has nothing to do with the previous work. In other words, I said restoring it for easy understanding, but it's not a restore job.

Comment: I don't see any way to do that. There's no way to know which lines should be removed and replaced with `<!-- talend template tag -->`. Could you add markers like `<!-- begin addition>` and `<!-- end additions>` when doing the replacement? Then you can remove everything between those two lines.